# Can a function be given after an XPath seperator?

Tags: xpath-2.0

Here is a XML.......

```
<Book id="isbn-0-671-21280-X">
    <Title>How to Read a Book</Title>
    <Subtitle>The Classic Guide to Intelligent Reading</Subtitle>
    <Author>Mortimer J. Adler</Author>
    <Author>Charles Van Doren</Author>
    <Date>1940</Date>
    <Publisher>Simon &amp; Schuster</Publisher>
</Book>
```

I want to get the length of attribute `id` of `Book`

I wrote:

```
string-length(//Book/@id)
```

and one more:

```
//Book/string-length(@id)
```

Both are working, but I have doubts that the second way is fully correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath 2 both ways are correct

You should not think about `/` as path anymore, but more like a map operator. Applying the function on the right to each element in the sequence to the left.

You can even do stuff like

```
//Book/(a-function-that-returns-nodes() | b-function-that-returns-nodes())/../..
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between those two kinds of calling a function. `string-length(//some/expression)` fetches all results of the path expression and then calculates the string length, `//some/expression/string-length()` will return the string length for every single matching result of that expression.

As your XML only includes one book, both versions will yield the same result. If there would be multiple books, the first query would return the summed up string length of all books, the second would return a string length for each book's identifier.

---

You could also write `//book/@id/string-lenght()` instead of `//Book/string-length(@id)` as there may not be more than one `@id` attribute, for other attributes (or subelements) the same as stated above would apply.

Comment: No it's not giving the summed  up result, instead it's giving the length of all the id's separately.

Comment: I explained this difference in the first parenthesis of my answer.